# sorting an array by item type

Tags: php

I have created some code to sort an array, but I think there are better ways to implement it. I need letters to be first, then numbers and characters to be the last. Any ideas how to optimize the code?

```
$array = array(1, '1', 'в', 'd', '!', 'y', '3', '#', '2', 'Z', 'a', 'Ё', 'і', 6, '1', '~',);
     usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
          if(is_numeric($a) && is_numeric($b)) {
               return $a - $b;
          }
          if(preg_match('/^[^\d\w]/u', $a) && preg_match('/^[^\d\w]/u', $b)) {
               return strcmp($a, $b);
          }
          if(preg_match('/^[^\d\w]/u', $a)) {
               return 1;
          }
          if(preg_match('/^[^\d\w]/u', $b)) {
               return -1;
          }
          if(is_numeric($a) && !is_numeric($b)) {
               return 1;
          }
          if(!is_numeric($a) && is_numeric($b)) {
               return -1;
          }
          return strcmp(mb_strtolower($a, 'utf-8'), mb_strtolower($b, 'utf-8'));
     });

      var_export($array);
```

The result should be like this:

```
array (
  0 => 'a',
  1 => 'd',
  2 => 'y',
  3 => 'Z',
  4 => 'в',
  5 => 'Ё',
  6 => 'і',
  7 => '1',
  8 => '1',
  9 => 1,
  10 => '2',
  11 => '3',
  12 => 6,
  13 => '!',
  14 => '#',
  15 => '~',
)
```

And another option, the result is the same but works faster.

```
$parts = array('/^[[:alpha:]]/u', '/^[\d]/u', '/^[^\d\w]/u');
$result = array();
    foreach ($parts as $regexp) {
        $part = preg_grep($regexp, $array);
        natcasesort($part);
        $result = array_merge($result, $part);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. might be a better way, but one way to streamline what you have there is by using a switch statement:

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    switch(true) {
        case (is_numeric($a) && is_numeric($b)):
            return $a - $b;
            break
        case (preg_match('/^[^\d\w]/u', $a) && preg_match('/^[^\d\w]/u', $b)):
            return strcmp($a, $b);
            break;
        case (preg_match('/^[^\d\w]/u', $a)):
        case (is_numeric($a) && !is_numeric($b)):
            return 1;
            break;
        case (preg_match('/^[^\d\w]/u', $b)):
        case (!is_numeric($a) && is_numeric($b)):
            return -1;
            break;
        default:
            return strcmp(mb_strtolower($a, 'utf-8'), mb_strtolower($b, 'utf-8')):
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you mean to have empty cases? Also, is it necessary to break after return?

Comment: Empty cases without breaks drop down to the next.. so the two spots where the case is empty end up going to the same return.  So yes, empty cases are intentional... it's basically a way to say "do this same thing for all these cases".

You can also do something like:
    case "something":
      dosomething();
    case "something2":
      dosomething2():
      break;

In a case like that, "something" will trigger both dosomething() and dosomething2() whereas "something2" will only trigger dosomething2().

Comment: Breaks aren't necessary after the returns but I like to be consistent in my code so I always use a break on cases and always include a default.  It's a little superfluous but if I scan over code and DON'T see those, I assume something's wrong.  So it's just a way to be consistent to aid in finding code errors.

Comment: Code is for programmers... some people will say to keep code super streamlined, but it should be easy to read and maintain for programmers.  The only time trimming out extra formatting and such things is when you're looking at HTML or CSS or JS and trying to keep the byte count down for faster page loads and rendering.